# VBA prefill worksheet in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, function, worksheet

I need to create a macro (by a recording that will pre-fill the spreadsheet with years in
column A) so that in the cell A1 we obtain 1950, in A2 1951 and so on and so forth,
until 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code. It fills an array with the result of rows range evaluation:

```
Sub YearsOnAACol()
   Dim arrY
   arrY = Evaluate("row(1950:2014)")
   Range("A6").Resize(UBound(arrY), 1).Value = arrY
End Sub
```

There are more other ways, but you must search on internet and find solutions by yourself.

I made an exception, only because you are a beginner. Please, learn that next time nobody will answer a question not proving anything about your personal contribution of solving the problem...